# How to convert JSON query?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, json

here is my JSON Output I got:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "return":{
    "an":[
      {
        "ordner_id":1,
        "name":"Eingang",
        "gesamt":"1415",
        "ungelesen":"0"
      },
      {
        "ordner_id":3,
        "name":"Gel\u00f6scht"
      },
      {
        "ordner_id":"42864",
        "name":"Test1",
        "gesamt":"0",
        "ungelesen":"0"
      }
    ],
    "von":[
      {
        "ordner_id":2,
        "name":"Gesendet"
      },
      {
        "ordner_id":3,
        "name":"Gel\u00f6scht"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I can get the "success" and the "return" value easily (BOOL and NSDictonary) with this lines:

```
 NSDictionary *ensFolderListFirstReturn = [ENSHandler GetENSFolderList];
BOOL success = [[ensFolderListFirstReturn objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue];  
if (success)
{
    ensFolderList = [ensFolderListFirstReturn objectForKey:@"return"];
}
```

But when I try to get the "an"-value with this:

```
 NSDictionary *ensFolderList1 = [ensFolderList objectForKey:@"an"];
```

I got a BAD EXEC-error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bear in mind that you do not own the object returned by `ensFolderList = [ensFolderListFirstReturn objectForKey:@"return"];` and depending on *when* you are trying to do `[ensFolderList objectForKey:@"an"]`, the object pointed by `ensFolderList ` might have been deallocated and you are now the proud owner of a dangling pointer. Also, the object associated with the key `an` is an array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the "an" value holds a list, not a dictionary. Try:

```
NSArray *ensFolderList1 = [ensFolderList objectForKey:@"an"];
```

Each element of that array will hold an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to directly getting an NSDictionary object from an NSDictionary. I don't think that this is a good way. Try to get the NSArray object from the NSDictionary like:

`NSArray *ensFolderArray = [ensFolderList objectAtIndex:0];`

`NSLog(@"%@",ensFolderArray);`

Now try to see on console that are you getting the required "an" object or not and give your response.

Happy Coding!